# What is the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore equivalent for watchOS?

Tags: icloud, cloudkit, watchos, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore, watchos-7

`App Groups` is sadly not supported on watchOS still and [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore) is available for every platform except watchOS. I've read the [Keeping Your watchOS Content Up to Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/keeping_your_watchos_content_up_to_date) and mentions iCloud and they make it sound so easy but don't provide an example. It seems I have to create a whole client-side `CloudKit` infrastructure to support it and seems like overkill, then requires the rest of the platforms to do the same just because watchOS is the odd ball.

Is there a simple key/value iCloud store equivalent in watchOS that I'm missing? It seems really difficult to share cloud data when you add watchOS to the mix. I tried using the iPhone as a source of truth and communicate with watchOS, but was very clunky and requires them to be in range with each other or they become out of sync. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is available starting with watchOS 9.0

Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore